# Constructor not called on static attribute

Tags: dart

I have a class with static final attributes and I store all the values in a list :

```
class Foo {

  static final Foo ATTRIBUTE_ONE = Foo(0);
  static final Foo ATTRIBUTE_TWO = Foo(1);
  static final Foo ATTRIBUTE_THREE = Foo(2);

  static List<Foo> VALUES = new List();

  int _index;

  Foo(this._index) {
    VALUES.add(this);
  }

  static Foo of(int index) {
    return VALUES.firstWhere((value) => value._index == index);
  }
}
```

But when I call the `of` method, `VALUES` is empty. If I inspect one of the attributes with Android Studio debugger, it is then added to the `VALUES` list.

How to force the call of the constructor to all the attributes ?

Answer (score 2):

As written in the Dart tour guide:

> Static variables aren’t initialized until they’re used.

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#class-variables-and-methods

For a solution to your problem I would suggest to use an Enum combined with a mapping method to be used if you need to translate the Enum value to a numeric value (and reverse).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `const` values to ensure that the values are evaluated (instead of static fields, which are lazy).

```
class Foo {
  static const Foo foo1 = Foo(1);
  static const Foo foo2 = Foo(2);
  static const Foo foo3 = Foo(3);  
  static const List<Foo> values = [Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)]; // or [foo1, foo2, foo3]
  final int _index;
  const Foo(this._index);
  static Foo of(int index) {
    for (var value in values) if (value._index == index) return value;
    return null;
  }
}
```

This allows direct access to the individual values as `foo1` etc, and also gives you a list of the same values.

If you don't want constants, you can also create the *values* field lazily:

```
class Foo {
  static final Foo ATTRIBUTE_ONE = Foo(0);
  static final Foo ATTRIBUTE_TWO = Foo(1);
  static final Foo ATTRIBUTE_THREE = Foo(2);
  static List<Foo> VALUES = [ATTRIBUTE_ONE, ATTRIBUTE_TWO, ATTRIBUTE_THREE];
  int _index;
  Foo(this._index);
  static Foo of(int index) {
    return VALUES.firstWhere((value) => value._index == index);
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution :

```
class Foo {

  static List<Foo> VALUES = [Foo(0), Foo(1), Foo(2)];

  int _index;

  Foo(this._index);

  static Foo of(int index) {
    return VALUES.firstWhere((value) => value._index == index);
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to remove the `add` from the constructor, so you might get *more* than one of each element in the list. If all you use it for is `of`, which finds the first matching value, then that doesn' matter, but it is still a waste of space.

Comment: You're right I forgot to remove it from the code for SO, I edit it